# How can I override the components of a vector entered by a user with new values?

Tags: c, vector, overriding

Just started learning C, and it would be great if you could help me with the following:

I just wrote a program that saves a 4-component vector entered by the user (using function called `save_vector`), prints it (using function called `print_vector`) and if any component is negative, it also prints it with all components in absolute value (positives) using the function `absolute_values`.

Now I would like to only work with the vector that has the absolute values. How could I save the new absolute values into the same vector and override the ones entered by the user?

Looking forward to reading any suggestions to improve this piece of code! Thank you! :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_vector(int N,float * V);
void save_vector(int N,float * V);
void absolute_values(int N, float * V);



int main(void)
{

    const int n=5;
    int i;
    float v[n];

    puts("Enter the 5 components of the vector:");
    save_vector(n, v);

    puts("\nThe vector is:");
    print_vector(n, v);

    puts("\nThe absolute vector is:");
    absolute_values(n, v);

    return 0;
}

void save_vector(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        scanf("%f",V+i);
}

void print_vector(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf(" %.2f ",*(V+i));
}

void absolute_values(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        printf(" %.2f ", ((V[i]<0)?-V[i]:V[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Plain and simple assignment? `V[i] = the_absolute_value_of(V[i])`?

Comment: On another note, please try to be consistent in your code. Don't mix different types of expressions for things that mean the same thing. Case in point: Either use only `V[i]` everywhere (my recommendation) or use only `*(V + i)`.

Comment: Just do `v[i] = fabs(v[i]);` for the elements you wish to change.  Include `math.h` to get `fabs`, and link with `-lm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just leaving here the final answer after reviewing the comment section and following @Some programmer dude advice! :-)

```
void print_vector(int N,float * V);
void save_vector(int N,float * V);
void absolute_values(int N, float * V);



int main(void)
{

    const int n=5;
    int i;
    float v[n];

    puts("Enter the 5 components of the vector:");
    save_vector(n, v);

    puts("\nThe vector is:");
    print_vector(n, v);

    puts("\nThe absolute vector is:");
    absolute_values(n, v);

    return 0;
}

void save_vector(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        scanf("%f",V+i);
}

void print_vector(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf(" %.2f ",*(V+i));
}

void absolute_values(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        V[i]=((V[i]<0)?-V[i]:V[i]);
        printf(" %f", V[i]);
    }
}
```